# "apt-get update" no longer working

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates

I can no longer update any packages in Ubuntu.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://debian.sur5r.net trusty InRelease                                   
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                       
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Err http://debian.sur5r.net trusty Release.gpg                                 
  Connection failed [IP: 217.8.49.41 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg                     
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
...
```

This is happening on:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

It seems like `apt-get update` thinks that 14.04.4 is at "end-of-life" (EOL).

```
$ ubuntu-support-status
Support status summary of 'travel':


You have 1267 packages (100.0%) that can not/no-longer be downloaded
You have 0 packages (0.0%) that are unsupported

Run with --show-unsupported, --show-supported or --show-all to see more details
```

This is pretty annoying. Any ideas?

---

UPDATE #1

I ran the following:

```
$ sudo strace -s 1024 apt-get update
...
read(7, "400 URI Failure\nURI: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease\nMessage: Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]\nTransient-Failure: true\n\n", 64000) = 162
...
```

Yet, when I use `curl`, I don't get a failure on the given URL:

```
$ curl -I "http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2016 23:16:18 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Thu, 03 Mar 2016 23:10:00 GMT
ETag: "10156-52d2d1903a200"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 65878
Cache-Control: max-age=2921, s-maxage=3300, proxy-revalidate
Expires: Fri, 04 Mar 2016 00:05:00 GMT
```

Does anyone know how to manually reinstall Aptitude and its dependencies? It seems like something is fundamentally broken.

---

UPDATE #2

OK, this is really strange!

I played around with proxying the requests, and the substantive difference was in the User-Agent header. More specifically, I found that Aptitude's default user agent (i.e., "Debian APT-HTTP/1.3") was being blocked. This occurred both over a WiFi connection and a tethered cellphone connection. I resolved the issue by instructing Aptitude to use a different user agent as outlined in [this article](http://samhassell.com/apt-cant-see-sources-try-changing-the-user-agent/).

**Conspiracy Theory:** I'm presently in South Africa, and I swear that I've updated successfully from this country before. Is this some NSA ploy to prevent people from patching the [DROWN (CVE-2016-0800)](https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv/20160301.txt) vulnerability in OpenSSL?

Comment: @clearkimura took the words right out of my mouth :D